# Ruby - How do I pass an array and function within another function's arguments?

Tags: arrays, ruby, function, callback

I am wondering how I can pass an array and function within another function's arguments. In the code below I am getting a `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`.

It takes an array `students` and callback named `callback`. `is_female` is the function I am trying to call.

```
students = [
    {name: 'John', grade: 8, gender: 'M'},
    {name: 'Sarah', grade: 12, gender: 'F'}
]
def is_female(students)
  students.find_all{ |item| item[:gender] == 'F' }
end
def filter_gender(students, &callback)
  callback(students)
end

p filter_gender(students, is_female)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting a wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

In many other languages, `is_female()` would invoke the method whereas `is_female` would return a reference to the method. In Ruby, the parentheses are optional and both variants are equivalent – they invoke the method.

Getting a reference to a method in Ruby is a little more involved: you have to call [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#method-method) passing the method's *name*. The result is an instance of [`Method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Method.html) – an object wrapper around your method:

```
m = method(:is_female)
#=> #<Method: main.is_female>

m.paramters
#=> [[:req, :students]]

m.call(students)  # <- equivalent to is_female(students)
#=> [{:name=>"Sarah", :grade=>12, :gender=>"F"}]
```

This object can be assigned to variables or be passed to other methods as a [positional](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Positional+Arguments) or [keyword](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) argument just like any other object.

`&callback` however is a [block argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument), so the method object has to be [converted to a block via `&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Proc+to+Block+Conversion):

```
m = method(:is_female)
filter_gender(students, &m)

# or in one line:

filter_gender(students, &method(:is_female))
```

There are actually two steps: `&` first invokes [`Method#to_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Method.html#method-i-to_proc) and then passes the result as the block argument. So within `filter_gender`, the `callback` variable doesn't refer to the method object, but to its proc. (another level of indirection)

Fortunately, `Method` and `Proc` have a similar interface for invocation: there's [`Proc#call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Proc.html#call-method), [`Proc#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D) or `prc.()`: (syntactic sugar for `call`)

```
callback.call(students)

callback[students]

callback.(students)
#       ^
#  note the dot
```

Applied to your code:

```
def filter_gender(students, &callback)
  callback.call(students)
end

filter_gender(students, &method(:is_female))
#=> [{:name=>"Sarah", :grade=>12, :gender=>"F"}]
```

---

Some suggestions:

I'd move the filtering and retrieval of the student's gender out of the method and into `filter_gender`:

```
def is_female(gender)
  gender == 'F'
end

def filter_gender(students, &callback)
  students.select { |item| callback.call(item[:gender]) }
end

filter_gender(students, &method(:is_female))
#=> [{:name=>"Sarah", :grade=>12, :gender=>"F"}]
```

And instead of invoking `callback` explicitly, I'd just `yield` the gender to the block and call it using a regular block: (you can combine the above and below code in either way)

```
def filter_gender(students)
  students.select { |item| yield item[:gender] }
end

filter_gender(students) { |gender| is_female(gender) }
#=> [{:name=>"Sarah", :grade=>12, :gender=>"F"}]
```

Instead of a method you could create a [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Proc.html) explicitly which can be passed as a block argument just via `&`:

```
is_female = -> (gender) { gender == 'F' }

filter_gender(students, &is_female)
#=> [{:name=>"Sarah", :grade=>12, :gender=>"F"}]
```

---

And last not least, you could create a `Student` class and implement a `female?` method:

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name, :grade, :gender

  def initialize(name:, grade:, gender:)
    @name   = name
    @grade  = grade
    @gender = gender
  end

  def female?
    gender == 'F'
  end
end

students = [
  Student.new(name: 'John', grade: 8, gender: 'M'),
  Student.new(name: 'Sarah', grade: 12, gender: 'F')
]

students.select(&:female?)
#=> [#<Student:0x00007fa8d186e350 @name="Sarah", @grade=12, @gender="F">]
```

Comment: OP, you were missing `callback.call` or `callback.()` for your code to work.. The `&callback` will capture the block in the `callback` variable but you have to call `#call` or the `.()` syntax to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby placing the method name in your code is equivalent to invoking that method (since parentheses are contextually optional), when what you want is a reference for the method.  Methods can be referenced by a symbol (the method name prefixed with ':') or string containing the method's name.  The method can be invoked by calling `send` with the method reference as the first argument, followed by any arguments the method requires.

Try the following:

```
students = [
    {name: 'John', grade: 8, gender: 'M'},
    {name: 'Sarah', grade: 12, gender: 'F'}
]

def is_female(students)
  students.find_all{ |item| item[:gender] == 'F' }
end

def filter_gender(students, callback)
  send(callback, students)
end

p filter_gender(students, :is_female)
```

I've used this successfully to implement a discrete event simulation Ruby gem, where the gem doesn't need any modification to run your model with arbitrary numbers of events and event names of your choosing.

Comment: That also returns `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)`

Comment: @StasysMeclazcke Did you copy and paste my code, or transcribe it (with possible errors)?  What I posted is a copy/paste of code that ran on my computer, producing `[{:name=>"Sarah", :grade=>12, :gender=>"F"}]`.